# Grammar for a JSON-like language

Tags: antlr4

I am trying to devise a grammar for a JSON-like language. The main differences are that property names need not be double quoted (they can be though), and that numbers are only integers (no floating point numbers).

This is one example:

```
{
  "property1": "string value",
  property2: 321,
  arr: [1,2,3]
}
```

This is my (attempt at) grammar:

```
grammar Command;

command: object;

object:   '{' pair (',' pair)* '}' ;

pair: name ':' value ;

name
   : '"' ID '"'
   | ID
   ;

value
    :   string
    |   integer
    |   object
    |   array
    |   bool
    ;

array: '[' value (',' value)* ']' ;

string: STRING ;

integer
      : ZERO
      | NONZERO 
      ;

bool
   : 'true' 
   | 'false' 
   ;

ID : [a-zA-Z0-9_]+ ;
STRING: '"' (ESC | .)*? '"' ;
fragment ESC: '\\"' | '\\\\' ;

ZERO: '0' ;
NONZERO: '-'? [1-9] [0-9]* ; 
WS  :   [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip ;
```

However, trying to run the TestRig on my example input, I get

```
line 2:2 no viable alternative at input '"property"'
line 3:10 no viable alternative at input '321'
line 4:8 no viable alternative at input '1'
line 4:10 no viable alternative at input '2'
line 4:12 no viable alternative at input '3'
```

Any ideas where I going wrong?

Thanks for your time!

Tuomas

Comment: Looks like your `name` rule has spaces between the quotes and the ID.

Comment: json is language nowadays? I thought it was a format :-)

Comment: Marco, pardon for the inaccuracy. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The lexer is creating a single `STRING` token for `"property"`, so you should adjust the `name` rule:

  ```
  name : STRING | ID;
  ```
- You need to move the `ID` rule after `ZERO` and `NONZERO`. Since your numbers also match the `ID` lexer rule, they'll be assigned a token type according to the first rule appearing in the grammar. You want the first rule to be `ZERO` or `NONZERO`, where currently it's `ID`. (Since all of your numbers are currently resulting in `ID` tokens, and `ID` is not allowed as a `value`, you get the syntax errors.)

Comment: Thank you very much! Your advice helped me solve the problem. Funny, I am reading "The Definitive Antlr4 Reference", and I had forgotten that the order of tokens matters. :-)